# I found apps that I have not installed. How can I investigate this?

Tags: security

There are 6 apps on my phone that I haven't explicitly or implicitly installed.

Most likely they were installed today, as they happened to get on the first screen/page, so I immediately noticed them.

Of course I didn't use the web/desktop Play Store to install them. And chances of the phone being unlocked in my pocket and installs 6 apps by mistake are none.

What is even more suspicious is that when I go to to Play Store, the apps show (install) button instead of (open), as if Play Store couldn't detects that they are installed.

How can I investigate this?

- HUAWEI Mate 10 pro
- Model BLA-L29
- EMUI version 9
- Android version 9
- Non-rooted

The applications are:

- Asphalt Nitro_com.gameloft.android.GloftANPH
- Assassin's Creed Unity
- Arno's Chronicles_com.playwing.acu.huawei Dragon
- Mania_com.gameloft.android.GloftPDMF
- Kingdoms_com.gameloft.android.GloftDMKF Spider-Man Ultimate
- Power_com.gameloft.android.GloftSMIF

I extracted them with an APK extractor.

Comment: The fact these apps show as not installed in the play store is very telling... they were not installed via the Play Store at all but from a 3rd party source. This likely means you have some kind of malware on your device. I would immediately backup all important data and factory reset your device, then only install apps directly from the Play Store afterwards. If you need some apps that are not available in the Play Store, turn on Unknown Sources, install the app, then disable Unknown Sources immediately afterwards.

Comment: Actually, in Android 9 this is an app level permission now. Look in Settings - Apps & Notifications, Special app access, Install Unknown Apps, and see what apps are listed as Allowed, if any are, you had to specifically give that app permission to install a 3rd party app. Often this is Chrome. I really don't like the new Android 8+ system for doing this, it has some dangerous potential because once you grant permission to install a 3rd party app, that app has permission to do so forever unless you turn it off manually... For Chrome, or any browser, that could be disastrous.

Comment: You were right, Chrome was allowed, among some other apps. Is there any way to verify that those apps were installed by Chrome? And most importantly, there should be no harm if the apps are not opened, or opened without getting any permissions. Right?

Comment: And I don't remember being prompted by Chrome to install any app. Being allowed to install apps, doesn't mean that they are allowed to do it without my confirmation?

Comment: There is no way to verify what app(s) Chrome installed, but there is also no way an app can get this permission unless you allow it manually. The pop-up window is a system prompt, it can't really be misinterpreted unless you chose not to read it. Some apps would legitimately require this permission, like alternative app stores, and in some cases Chrome as well if you have to install apps that are not in the Play Store (some of GSAM's extensions and XDA Labs come to mind).

Comment: One option would be to look at your Chrome downloads for any "apk" file, that is an Android application. If there are any, it would also tell you what site it was downloaded from.

Comment: What are the applications in question ?